# TThread.Queue overload not found

Tags: delphi

This simple program doesn't compile. [Tested with XE5 and D10.]

```
program Project10;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Classes;

function MakeProc: TThreadProcedure;
begin
  Result := procedure begin end;
end;

begin
  TThread.Queue(nil, MakeProc);
end.
```

Compiler reports error

> [dcc32 Error] Project10.dpr(16): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'Queue' that can be called with these arguments

in the `TThread.Queue` call.

Class `TThread` implements two `Queue` overloads.

```
class procedure Queue(const AThread: TThread; AMethod: TThreadMethod); overload; static;
class procedure Queue(AThread: TThread; AThreadProc: TThreadProcedure); overload; static;
```

I'm pretty sure that my code should match the second overload.

The only workaround I was able to find is this:

```
TThread.Queue(nil, procedure begin MakeProc; end);
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this a compiler bug? Is there a better workaround than my ugly hack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler evidently thinks you're trying to pass `MakeProc` itself as the argument. You can tell the compiler that you intend to *call* that function instead by adding parentheses, just as you would if the function took parameters:

```
TThread.Queue(nil, MakeProc());
```

Your workaround wouldn't seem to work. It would compile and run, but the function returned by `MakeProc` would never execute. Instead, the anonymous method *wrapping* `MakeProc` would run, call `MakeProc`, and then discard that function's result. (Since the function's result doesn't do anything in the code you've provided, you might not have noticed the difference.)

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me! I run into this "feature" of Pascal language from time to time and then I promptly forget about it. :(

Comment: I tend to use always the brackets, even if I did not have to use them (f.i. C# forces you to write the empty brackets), just to keep the difference in mind :o)

Answer (score 0):

TThread.Queue method takes anonymous procedure as an argument. You cannot reference usual procedure in place of anonymous procedure. But you can call overloaded TThread.Queue method which takes class method reference as an argument. See example below:

```
type
  TMyTestClass = class
  public
    procedure ThreadProc;
  end;

{ TMyTestClass }

procedure TMyTestClass.ThreadProc;
begin
  WriteLn('We are in thread');
end;

var
  MyTestClass: TMyTestClass;
begin
  with TMyTestClass.Create do
  try
    TThread.Queue(nil, ThreadProc);
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Your example is not so good. The `MyTestClass` object is most likely destroyed before the call to ThreadProc is done.

Comment: This is wrong. The method accepts any method reference. An anonymous method is a method reference, but any other method reference will work, too. In fact, the code you've posted demonstrates exactly that.